# Docker 19.03.12 : The swarm does not have a leader aferter swarm upgrade

Tags: docker, cluster-computing, upgrade, swarm

Some strange troubleshouting with docker since laste update.

Can you help me about this ?
It’s is not my firstr upgrade of package and this case have been reproduice on a freshnew stack.

Updgraded from 18.09.9 to 19.03.12

OS : Ubuntu 16.04 Server

Docker package

```
docker-ce=5:18.09.9~3-0~ubuntu-bionic
docker-ce-cli=5:19.03.11~3-0~ubuntu-bionic
containerd.io=1.2.13-2
```

Details

A problem identified with version 19.03.12 of docker
Managers have been put in version 19.03.12
When you want to add a manager to the group with an active leader, an error message is visible
The different known solutions were used

Case

- As soon as you play the docker swarm join --token command on non-leader managers, after a few minutes, the leader manager is no longer available
  -> Forced to replay the docker swarm init command --force-new-cluster --advertise-addr xx.xx.xx.xx --listen-addr xx.xx.xx.xx: 2377 to find the leader operational
- The leader sees the worker nodes in version 19.03.12. No problem with workers

Restarting the docker service leads to the same result

Error Message

The swarm does not have a leader
Error response from daemon: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = The swarm does not have a leader. It's possible that too few managers are online. Make sure more than half of the managers are online.
docker msg="error reading the kernel parameter net.ipv4.vs.expire_nodest_conn"

References applied
[https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/34384#:~:text=demote%20master%20...-,new-server%23%20docker%20node%20ls%20Error%20response%20from%20daemon%3A,too%20few%20managers%20are%20online.&text=have%20a%20leader.-,It%27s%20possible%20that%20too%20few%20managers%20are%20online.,of%20the%20managers%20are%20online.](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/34384#:%7E:text=demote%20master%20...-,new-server%23%20docker%20node%20ls%20Error%20response%20from%20daemon%3A,too%20few%20managers%20are%20online.&text=have%20a%20leader.-,It%27s%20possible%20that%20too%20few%20managers%20are%20online.,of%20the%20managers%20are%20online.)

[Docker Node is Down after service restart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50933171/docker-node-is-down-after-service-restart)

https://cynici.wordpress.com/2018/05/31/docker-info-rpc-error-on-manager-node/
https://gitmemory.com/issue/docker/swarmkit/2670/481951641
https://forums.docker.com/t/cant-add-third-swarm-manager-or-create-overlay-network-the-swarm-does-not-have-a-leader/50849
https://askubuntu.com/questions/935569/how-to-completely-uninstall-docker

Comment: Hello.

The subject is still open.

Nobody with enough knowledge to help me ?

Thanks